# Seize by condition - AnyLogic

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

Assume I have 2 resources - x and y.
How can I make conditional seize by a parameter of y?

On the seize block, the customise resource choice has been selected and the resource choice condition is:

(y)unit).parameter >= 3, but it raised an error :” can’t cast x to y “.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where in your model do you do this operation? Inside ResourcePool for x?

Comment: In the seize block

Comment: Please add screenshots, otherwise difficult to understand. Also explain what is your goal and what else have you tried.

Comment: There has been added information to the question. Have any suggestion ?

Comment: `y.parameter >= 3` doesn't work?

Comment: “Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field y.parameter “

Comment: Please search this error, there have been plenty of questions and answers on SOF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if x and y are different resource types then you can do in your resource choice

```
unit instanceof Y ? ((Y)unit).parameter >= 3 : true
```